# как удалить метку (tag) в репозитарии origin

Tags: git

Создал метку, потом отправил её в удалённый репозиторий. Потом удалил её же локально удалил, т.к. неверно выставил. Выставил метку правильно. Но  команда `git push --tags` заканчивается с ошибкой:

```
    git push --verbose --force --tags
Отправка в ssh://git@any:24268/data-converters
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: FATAL: + refs/tags/release_300.4_013 data-converters gituser DENIED by fallthru
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/tags/release_300.4_013
remote: FATAL: + refs/tags/release_300.4_014 data-converters gituser DENIED by fallthru
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/tags/release_300.4_014
To ssh://git@any:24268/data-converters
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_001 -> release_300.4_001
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_002 -> release_300.4_002
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_003 -> release_300.4_003
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_006 -> release_300.4_006
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_007 -> release_300.4_007
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_008 -> release_300.4_008
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_009 -> release_300.4_009
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_010 -> release_300.4_010
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_011 -> release_300.4_011
 = [up to date]      release_300.4_012 -> release_300.4_012
 = [up to date]      release_300.5_001 -> release_300.5_001
 ! [remote rejected] release_300.4_013 -> release_300.4_013 (hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] release_300.4_014 -> release_300.4_014 (hook declined)
error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «ssh://git@any:24268/data-converters»
```

Comment: А вообще, `hook declined to update` намекает на то, что на сервере стоит гит-хук. Содержимое его нам неизвестно, так что нельзя точно сказать, что ему не нравится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Явным образом удалите тег с origin'а:

```
git push --delete origin tagname
```